# Erase git branch that got duplicated with the same name

Tags: git

I tried to do a pull on a branch.

I verified the selected branch with `git branch`and **dev** was selected (which was the one I intended)

I did `git pull` and obtained:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
```

Then, `git checkout dev` to assure the branch was selected and obtained:

```
error: pathspec 'dev' did not match any file(s) known to git.
git checkout -b dev
Switched to a new branch 'dev'
```

And now  when running `git branch` I have two **dev** branches.
Why has this happened and how can I solve it?
Are both the same branch?
Am I in any danger of losing files changes by erasing one of them?

Comment: What is the exact output of `git branch -avv`?

Answer (score 1):

> And now when running `git branch` I have two **dev** branches.

you should have **2** dev branches.
One is the remote branch `origin/dev` and the second one is your local branch that you have checked out.

To verify it you can use:

```
git branch    -> should output 1 dev
git branch -a -> should print the 2 branches (local on top and remote on bottom)
```

> Why has this happened and how can I solve it?

No need to resolve it, this is the way git works.

> Are both the same branch?

They are the same before you modified your local branch.

> Am I in any danger of losing files changes by erasing one of them?

Not unless you delete or push code to remote.

---

More info: 
[Git Branching - Basic Branching and Merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)